# Regarding bijectivity of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the map $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R,$ $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$
Munkres claims that it is an order preserving bijection.

To see it's order preserving, assume $x< y$. Then $x^2<y^2, 1-x^2 >1-y^2$, so $\frac{1}{1-x^2}<\frac{1}{1-y^2}$.

To show it is a bijection, I guess it's easiest to construct the inverse.

We have $y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}\iff yx^2+x-y=0$. But this equation has two solutions for $x$; how to see which one we need?

Comment: Note that $-0.1\lt 0.01$ but $0.01\not\lt 0.0001$. Do you perhaps intend the domain to be $(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Right, I shouldn't have squared two sides of an equality (I don't know whether they are non-negative)... Then how to prove that it preserves the order?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x \neq y$ but $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x$ and $y$.

It follows that $\frac{x}{1-x^2}=\frac{y}{1-y^2}$, that is, $y(1+xy)=x(1+xy)$ and since $1+xy\neq 0$ it follows that $x=y$, but we assumed $x \neq y$ so when $x\neq y$ we have $f(x)\neq f(y)$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick proof.

Recall that
$$\tan 2t=\frac{2\tan t}{1-\tan^2 t}.$$

Therefore
$$\frac{x}{1-x^2}=\frac12\tan(2\arctan x).$$
This is valid for $x\in(-1,1)$. On this interval
$\arctan$ is increasing, and on the interval
$(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so is $\tan$.

The inverse function is then
$$y\mapsto\tan\left(\frac{\arctan(2y)}2\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac x{1-x^2}=\frac{-x}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac x2\left(\frac 1{x+1}-\frac 1{x-1}\right)=-\frac 12\left(\frac 1{x+1}+\frac 1{x-1}\right)$$

Can you see now why $f$ is an order preserving bijection?

- $x\lt y\iff\dfrac 1{x\pm 1}\gt\dfrac 1{y\pm 1};$ so their sums preserve $\gt$; finally multiplying by $-1/2$ gives $f(x)\lt f(y)$
- Let $f(x)=f(y)$ and WLOG assume $x\leq y$. We need to show $x=y$ for bijectivity; so suppose not, ie $x\lt y$ and use the above argument to infer that $f(x)\lt f(y)$, a contradiction!